# Converting Babylon dictionary to StarDict dictionary

Tags: conversion, dictionary

After upgrading Ubuntu our administrator at work un-installed *GoldenDict* and instead of that installed *StarDict*. I had been using a lot of Babylon dictionaries in GoldenDict.

I have found out that *StarDict* doesn't support Babylon dictionaries and that I need to convert them. I found [`dictconv`](http://ktranslator.sourceforge.net/download.html) tool to convert Babylon dictionaries into *StarDict* dictionary. `dictconv` converts very well but once I add it to StarDict and want to see the result, *StarDict* shows results along with HTML tags, the result looks like this:

```
<--- An English-Spanish Dictionary (Granada University, Spain), 10.5 --->
write
<i> (v.)</i><i> = <b>escribir, redactar, confeccionar</b></i><br> <br>Def: <i>
Verbo irregular: pasado <b>wrote</b>, participio <b>written</b></i>.
<br> Ex: <i>A paraphrase is an interpretation of the concepts featured in a document, <b>written</b> in the language of the writer of the paraphrase</i>.<br> ----
```

Does anybody know other converters? or How can I solve this specific error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After searching in google have found finally what I was looking for.

So, in order to convert Babylon dictionary into StarDict I did following instructions:

- `sudo apt-get install stardict-tools` installing stardict-tools
- `stardict-editor` - openign stardict-editor
- An editor will be opened where you need to browse and select you .BGL file(Babylon Dictionary)
- In the bottom of the opened application you select `BGL file` and click on `Build` button
- It will create a file with an extension .babylon.
- Next browse and select this file
- In the bottom of the opened application you select `Babylon file` and click on `Build` button
- That's it. It will create 3 files (.dict.dz, .idx, .ifo) in the current directory
- Copy and paste it into one separate directory under StarDict dictionary folder.

That's it.